# Item carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im wondering how can I make the infinite auto scrolling stop, and when clicked the right arrow it will display per page not per item ?

```
$('.carousel.carousel-multi .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().attr("aria-hidden", "true").appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().attr("aria-hidden", "true").appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Here's the link to the demo https://codepen.io/ygoex/pen/meeaGw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the infinite auto scrolling just add this:

> data-interval="false"

Simply do this:

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="false" id="myCarousel">
```

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

**Here's the link to the working solution:** http://codepen.io/HenryGranados/pen/KWLweQ

Comment: is there a way that it wont loop back from the start ?

Answer (score 0):

To stop infinite auto scrolling you can use this code in js:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
pause: true,
interval: false
```

});

Inside Bootstrap "carousel-inner" class has "item" which full width by default which are behave like kind of block,so you can put as many items as want  to show in a page and control it using "col-" classes for designing responsive.